# How to send view file content in JSON from CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working with a project on CodeIgniter ajax base.

**What i want..?**

I want to load the page content by using JSON ajax...
When request will be generated from client machine. Controller will execute the view file by using dynamic values and then it will be return the view file HTML, breadcrumb menu items and some other stuff...

**This is my working code**

```
class Manage extends CI_Controller {
    public function contentHome() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $html = "Hello World... Hello World... ";
            $breadcrumb = array();

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb , 'pageContent' => $html, 'session' => true, 'redirect' => false));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('breadcrumb' => '' , 'pageContent' => '', 'session' => false, 'redirect' => site_url('manage/login')));
        }
    }
}
```

How i can replace this `$html = "Hello World... Hello World... ";` with my view file HTML

For more detail please find the attached file
[image]

Comment: use an Ajax get request to the file url and have the html of the page be returned?

Comment: I am already using ajax request... how i can get the all parameters in a single call..? I can get breadcrumb menu and session information. but unable to get the View File HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the request's are coming from ajax
and send back the relevant header response codes.
You want to catch any un-authorized(**401**) code in the ajax error handler

```
public function contentHome()
{
    // only allow ajax requests
    if(!this->input->is_ajax_request()) return;

    // you could also set some validation
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) 
        return $this->output->set_status_header("401"); // un-authorized

    // Or directly send stuff to the browser
    $data = array(
       'pageContent'  => $this->load->view('', null, true),
       'breadcrumbs'  => $breadcrumbs
    );

    return $this->output
                ->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($data));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution :)**

```
public function contentHome() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $html = $this->load->view('manage/contentHome', '', true);
            $breadcrumb = array();

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb , 'pageContent' => $html, 'session' => true));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('breadcrumb' => '' , 'pageContent' => '', 'session' => false, 'redirect' => site_url('manage/login')));
        }
    }
```